# How to take string as parameter for Rails path helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, parameter-passing, helper

I want to call a path helper like so

`link_to t, tag_path()`, where `t` is a string.

What is the best way to go about this?

---

Some more detail:

Normally, `t` would be a tag record, so I could do `tag_path(t)` to send me to the tag path with the tag's id. But I am restricted to a string, not an active record object or an integer.

I tried `tag_path(Tag.find_by_name(t))`, but gives me a browser error of `uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::Tag` probably because I am trying to call it from a view belonging to a controller other than tags_controller.

I don't want to cache a tag record in the controller because there can be tons of tags, and all the ones they don't click (if any) will be wasted queries.

If it's doing a find, it would be best if it's lazy loaded, so that it queries the database only when the user clicks on the link.

---

**Update:**

```
= raw(hack.cached_tag_list).split(', ').each{ |t| link_to t, tag_path(ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.find_by_name(t)) }.join(', ')
```

stored string data
`efficiency, food`

`= hack.cached_tag_list.split(', ')` results in `["efficiency", "food"]` printed on the browser

`= hack.cached_tag_list.split(', ').each { |t| t}` results in `["efficiency", "food"]` printed in the browser... very peculiar.

---

**Full solution:**

Bypassing dealing with methods that don't change, I instead did this in slim

```
- hack.cached_tag_list.split(',').each do |t|
  = link_to t.strip, tag_path(t.strip)
  ' ,
```

Comment: So now what's the problem? Still can't find the tag? Or the link is not building correctly? Show what the output is.

Comment: I may not be parsing it correctly. The output is unclickable text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there trying to find the tag by name but I think you have the namespace wrong. It could be you're using a Tagging gem such as ActsAsTaggable. In that case the Tag model would be under the Gem's namespace such as: `ActsAsTaggable::Tag`. So, you'd be able to find the tag by doing: `ActsAsTaggable::Tag.find_by_name(t)`.

Comment: Indeed I am using that gem. It's the reason why I'm limited to strings, since I am using a cache on the parent model to store the tag names in a pseudo-array of strings the cache column is a string type).

Comment: I'm still not getting it as a link. Perhaps since that query hasn't been run, it is not turning the link into a clickable link?

I'll update the OP with my exact code

Comment: oh wow. I tried putting in an explicit number, and it doesn't work.